# Why is the decrytedText NULL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cryptlib

My app receives encrypted data from a GET request. I'm having a problem decrypting the data. I'm using the cross-platform CryptLib Library, [CryptLib](https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption).  Followed the documentation in the CryptLib.m but nothing seems to work.  If anyone has some knowledge of CryptLib, some guidance would be much appreciated, Please see my code below.

Code

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * _Nullable encryptedData,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {
      //has data
      NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"Data received: %@", jsonData);


      NSString *key = @"3HS5UtP7hEc5Jsqg7P4KDQEH2y95v92Z";
      NSString *iv = @"ZkjH27Rh63RQtH8y";

    //Decrypted data is NULL!
      encryptedData = [[StringEncryption alloc] decrypt:encryptedData  key:key iv:iv];
      NSString * decryptedText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"decrypted data:: %@", decryptedText); //print the decrypted text


  }] resume];
```

Comment: does encryptedData has content after StringEncryption?

Comment: Yes, I think the issue is due to encoding of the NSString

Comment: Try to encode text and decode it in one function. Use the same Text you encoded in your Website. Just to make sure there is no issue on URLTask